# AWS S3 Using transferManager to make multipart upload by sending parts

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have recently learned about `TransferManager` class in AWS S3.
This behind the scenes creates multi-part upload, however it seems like I need to put whole file inside for it to work.

I receive my file in parts, so I need to create multipart upload manually. Is something like that possible using `TransferManager`? For example instead of

```
Upload upload = tm.upload(bucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));
```

to use for example something like

```
Upload upload = tm.upload(bucketName, keyName, partOfFile1);
Upload upload = tm.upload(bucketName, keyName, partOfFile2);
Upload upload = tm.upload(bucketName, keyName, partOfFile3);
```

Or am I stuck with `AmazonS3` class when I need to upload file by parts manually?

Thanks for help!

Comment: According to documentation, the whole point of TransferManager is to split file and upload parts in parallel and to improve performance. Why would you want to do it yourself?

Comment: as i said, i receive parts of the file from another service. I do not receive the whole fille at once. Yes I could store it but the file/files are too big and I cannot afford to store them at once.

Comment: Please update your question with a description of how you receive parts. Is it a chunked transfer from the client, messages on a queue, or something else? How large are the individual parts? Are they guaranteed to be received in order? And perhaps most important, do you know the final size up front?